# I am trying to migrate my application from jersey 2.25 to 3.x and deploying the application in weblogic 12.2.1.4 version and I am seeing this error

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic

Error:

```
<BEA-101126><[ServletContext@114317303 [app: xxx module: xxx.war path:null spec-version:3.1]] Error casting servlet: "xxx" to javax.servlet.Servlet
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebComponentContributor.createServletInstance(WebComponentContributor.java:274)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.newServletInstanceIfNecessary (StubSecurityHelper.java:378) at weblogic.servlet.internal. StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:330)
at weblogic.servlet.internal. StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:307)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal. AuthenticatedSubject. doAs (AuthenticatedSubject.java:344) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs ForUserCode (SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider. WlsSecurityProvider.runAs ForUserCode (WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider. WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet (StubSecurityHelper.java:87)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOne Instance (StubLifecycleHelper.java:74) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:31) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl. initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:676)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:615) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet (WebAppServletContext.java:2072)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup (WebAppServletContext.java:2849)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources (WebAppServletContext.java:1938) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start (WebAppServletContext.java:3194)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts (WebAppModule.java:1864)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:919)
at weblogic.application.internal. ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360) at weblogic.application.internal. ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
```

If anyone knows how to fix this issue pls help

Comment: It's trying to cast javax Servlet to jakarta Servlet. It doesn't look like the WebLogic you are using doesn't support Jakarta.

Answer (score 0):

See https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee

> The highest impact item in this stage, however, is changing the package name in all the Java APIs from javax.* to jakarta.*.

If you look at https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest3x/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html you'll see that it no longer extends javax.servlet.Servlet, as https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.25/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.html did.